retagging [tag:mywallet] --> [tag:blockchain.info]
There were only 5 questions tagged mywallet, most of those were also tagged blockchain.info anyway (and most of those were mine, too).
Hence, I've retagged them all to blockchain.info.

Sounds good to me.
